# Json array does not put values into database

Tags: php, mysql, json

Trying to put a $json array values into database but sadly it does not work for some reasons and i can't find it why. My first guess was it cause it maybe of varchar255 in mysql?

```
<?php
$json = '[
    {
        "order_id":123,
        "kases_id":12,
        "product_quantity":121,
        "product_name":"suns",
        "postage_adress":"garaazha",
        "barcode":"2131231"
    }
]';
//create a DB connection
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "qrbuddy");


$result = json_decode($json);
foreach($result as $key => $value) {
    if($value) {
        mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO qrbuddy (order_id, kases_id, product_quantity, product_name, postage_adress, barcode, status) VALUES ($value->order_id, $value->kases_id,$value->product_quantity,$value->product_name,$value->postage_adress,$value->barcode, 0)");
    }
    mysqli_close($connect);
}
?>
```

My database:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


CREATE TABLE `qrbuddy` (
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `kases_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `postage_adress` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `barcode` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
)
```

Comment: The `varchar` is just saying it can fit up to 255 characters in the field, that isn't your problem.

Comment: And this code works for me, perhaps it's a server issue? Are you getting any sql errors or anything?

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Does the first row get inserted? You shouldn't use `mysqli_close()` inside the foreach loop.

Comment: No, none of the values is getting inserted. mysqli_close() took it out from the foreach loop. Also no sql errors are popping out. @GrumpyCrouton

Comment: About server - i'm using XXAMP package.@GrumpyCrouton

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$result = json_decode($json);
foreach($result as $key => $value) {
    if($value) {
        mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `your_DATABASE_NAME`.`qrbuddy` (`order_id`, `kases_id`, `product_quantity`, `product_name`, `postage_adress`, `barcode`, `status`) VALUES ({$value->order_id}, {$value->kases_id},{$value->product_quantity},{$value->product_name},{$value->postage_adress},{$value->barcode}, 0)");

    }
    mysqli_close($connect);
}
```

Recently I noticed that I need to specify the Database name as well in order for a query to work 100%.

Edit: Forgot to specify, make sure you write your Database Name instead of *`your_DATABASE_NAME`*. Just making sure you won't waste to much time on this one :)

Also, from my own experience writing the variables inside curly brackets **{$variable}**, gives you higher % that the query will work. (And it's easier to read anyway =)

---